# Validate JWT Policy Per Operation or All Operations

Tags: jwt, azure-api-management

I currently have an API setup in Azure APIM with multiple operations.
I have implemented a JWT Bearer authentication policy on the **All Operations** section.

What I need to do now is implement the authorization part per operation based on the scopes returned in my token. I've looked at this example and understand what to do [API Authorization Restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT)

However, is it good/bad practice to try implement the policy on the root **All operations** and then in that policy check the operation being requested and write the code to match the correct scopes to operation.

Or should the JWT policy be copy/pasted for each operation and only that operations authorization logic then lives in there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So you're able to apply policies at the Global, Product , API and granular operation levels.

These policies are then evaluated together to form an **Effective Policy** for your request.

What I ended up doing was the applying the `validate-jwt` policy at the **All Operations**
level. This means that for any operation in my API, my token would be authenticated.

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Not authenticated, token invalid." output-token-variable-name="jwt">
        <openid-config url="redacted" />
        <audiences>
            <audience>redacted</audience>
        </audiences>
        <issuers>
            <issuer>redacted</issuer>
        </issuers>
    </validate-jwt>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

I then added policies to the operations to perform the authorization by checking the scopes parameter in my JWT token, using the `choose when` policy. You need to make sure that you add this after the `<base/>` policy element.

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(!((Jwt)context.Variables["jwt"]).Claims.GetValueOrDefault("scope").Contains("read:user"))">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="403" reason="Forbidden" />
            </return-response>
        </when>
    </choose>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```